# Upgrading TFS 2005 to TFS 2010 - Migrating Sharepoint site

Tags: tfs

I recently did a migration upgrade from TFS2005 to TFS2010.  Everything works, but the Sharepoint site wasn't migrated.

I attempted running the command below:

```
stsadm.exe -o addcontentdb -url http://NEWSERVER/sites -databasename STS_Content_TFS -databaseserver NEWDB
```

but I got the following error:

```
The pre-upgrade scan tool has not yet been run on this database SPContentDatabas
e Name=sts_content_tfs Parent=SPDatabaseServiceInstance. You must run the pre-up
grade scan tool before you can continue with the upgrade process. Run the tool f
rom the following path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Serve
r Extensions\12\bin\prescan.exe.
```

Unfortunately I have upgraded WSS from WSS2 to WSS3 on my source server, so I am unable to use prescan.exe.

Any other way to migrate the Sharepoint site from the old server to the new server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server: Connect to STS_Content_TFS
update Sites SET BitFlags = 262144

then follow steps here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668750.aspx